# Image Search In Folder PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an image from user and storing it in a folder. Now using the image name i have to search the image in that same folder.The image is stored correctly in the folder.For search i am using some thing like this :

```
     echo '<img src="upload/'.$thumb.'" " />';
```

the variable $thumb is having the image name.It is getting the image name like that :

```
    $thumb=$_POST['thumbnailPic'];
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific, i don't understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['thumbnailPic'])) {
   $thumb=$_REQUEST['thumbnailPic'];
  echo '<img src="upload/'.$thumb.'" />';
 }
else {
  die("no thumbnailPic is found!");

}
```

I think you have extra quotes in the image src :

```
 echo '<img src="upload/'.$thumb.'" " />';   
                                    ^---- this is extra quotes
```

Should be:

```
echo '<img src="upload/'.$thumb.'" />';
```

That quotes makes your `img` tag inavlid. Also check images permission

Comment: Still giving error of   Undefined index: thumbnailPic

Comment: this error means that you don not post a post data with the name `thumbnailPic`